# Power BI Count Number of Rows Below Median Score

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have one column with scores and need to calculate the count of rows at or below the median score of the column.

I tried the below formula but it appears I'm not allowed to use Median as a filter option.

```
Calculated Column = if('Table'[Score] < MEDIAN('Table'[Score]),1,0)
```

I was then just going to subtract the sum of the above from the total row count.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When you say Median as a filter, Do you mean a visual slicer ?

Comment: "cant be used as a filter" is regarding the "calculate" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution :-

I started with something like this,

```
**Table1**
Score
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I then created a Measure Called as Median with something like this,

```
Median = CALCULATE(MEDIAN(Table1[Score]),ALL(Table1))
```

Then, the below step is optional if you want to use in a table/graph to pick the outlier :-

```
? Below Median = (IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Score])<[Median],1,0))
```

Now, to calculate scores below Median, I used something like this :-

```
# of Scores Below Median = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Score]<[Median])))
```

These allowed me to generate something like below,

[image: The solution]

Kindly accept the answer if it helps and if it doesn't please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

you are never allowed to use Measures (Calculated Fields) (in your case Median) in a column calculation.

Try to store the median in one column for every row (same value).

So you have to use calculated column (median) = .. for the median first and then you can use this threshold in your original formal instead of median.

Comment: "you are never allowed to use Measures in a column calculation" - that's not true. You can use measures in calculated columns as much as you want.

Comment: but not in an if statement